# Error when dealing with file paths in windows and Python

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to create a directory with a variable as the name, with a folder inside it (also a variable). Currently, this is what I have:

```
### sort and copy files to backup
        if event.event_type == 'created':
            #modFile = event.src_path[:-1]
            chainFolderOut = backupDir + event.src_path
            print(chainFolderOut)
            print(event.src_path)
            chainFolderIn = chainFolderOut + '/' + str(timestamp)
            print(chainFolderIn)
            os.mkdir(chainFolderOut)
            os.mkdir(chainFolderIn)
```

This is the error I get when trying to run the program:

```
 /Users/Spencer/Desktop/backupTest/Users/Spencer/Desktop/TestWatchdog\New Text Document (4).txt
/Users/Spencer/Desktop/TestWatchdog\New Text Document (4).txt
/Users/Spencer/Desktop/backupTest/Users/Spencer/Desktop/TestWatchdog\New Text Document (4).txt/1537919413.7257273
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Spencer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Spencer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\watchdog\observers\api.py", line 199, in run
    self.dispatch_events(self.event_queue, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Spencer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\watchdog\observers\api.py", line 368, in dispatch_events
    handler.dispatch(event)
  File "C:\Users\Spencer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\watchdog\events.py", line 322, in dispatch
    self.on_any_event(event)
  File "C:\Users\Spencer\Desktop\tesseractAlpha1.0\tesseractAlpha2.0.py", line 53, in on_any_event
    os.mkdir(chainFolderOut)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '/Users/Spencer/Desktop/backupTest/Users/Spencer/Desktop/TestWatchdog\\New Text Document (4).txt'
```

What am I doing wrong here? event.src_path is the variable for full path of the file I want to deal with btw. I have no idea where that last slash is coming from before the file's name.
Ultimately, I am creating a program that watches for file changes in one directory, and then copies the changed file into a backup-folder/folder-named-after-the-file's-path>timestamp

Comment: Try putting `'C:'` in front of the string

Comment: Why are you making a _directory_ that ends in `New Text Document (4).txt`?  It's a legal name, I suppose, but very unusual.

Comment: Apparently `backupDir` is "/Users/Spencer/Desktop/backupTest" and `event.src_path` is "/Users/Spencer/Desktop/TestWatchdog\New Text Document (4).txt". You can't just concatenate those. You have to reconcile using either the "backupTest" or "TestWatchdog" directory under "Desktop".  And don't depend on "C:" being the working drive; use a fully-qualified path.

Comment: `os.path` package will save you a lot of trouble with different os paths.

Comment: When using either C: or c: in the file path, I get this error: 'code'
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'c:/Users/Spencer/Desktop/backupTestc:/Users/Spencer/Desktop/TestWatchdog\\New Text Document (6).txt''code'

Comment: When I run: 'code'            if event.event_type == 'created':
                chainFolderOut = backupDir + event.src_path
                print(chainFolderOut)
                print(event.src_path)
                chainFolderIn = chainFolderOut + '/' + str(timestamp)
                print(chainFolderIn)
               'code' I get: 'code'.../Spencer/Desktop/TestWatchdog\New Text Document (9).txt
/Users/Spencer/Desktop/TestWatchdog\New Text Document (9).txt
...Spencer/Desktop/TestWatchdog\New Text Document (9).txt/1537930666.4902241'code' Sorry had to shorten paths due to limit

Comment: Sorry to spam, but I do mean to combine the 2 filepaths. that way every time a file is copied to my backup directory it is saved by full filepath (as a folder) and then by its timestamp (also a folder). Also I am using "New Text Doc" just as a test file.